# FCM C++ Qt Client token refresh

Tags: android, c++, qt, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating FCM on my Qt app that will run on Android.
To init FCM I'm extending the c++ class ::firebase::messaging::Listener that notifies me when a token is created using the OnTokenReceived method.

In the same app I've also integrated a java class that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService and I've put it in the AndroidManifest as described in the documentation.

Now when a token is initially created my app correctly call at c++ level the OnTokenReceived method, but when the token is refreshed the "entry point" is at java level in the class that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService.

Is there a way to handle creation and refresh of tokens both at c++ level instead of mixing c++ and java classes?

I've read the google documentation for the c++ client integration but there is no reference to the "token refresh" action.